# Cross Domain Widget Issue -- Python, PHP, Chrome, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, widget, cross-domain

This should be a rather straight forward widget with the usual HTML js/div plugin code, but the issue here is that it won't display the echoed PHP code (output would be plain html on callback from the Python file in /cgi-bin/) within Chrome (the browser I'm testing on). When I run the python code below from the BASH shell it displays the echoed PHP code as plain HTML, but it is not displaying anything when I run the Plugin/HTML code below from within Chrome.

cgi.force_redirect = 0 is set within php.ini, so that shouldn't be the issue. Chrome previously threw an error for the PHP code callback due to cgi-bin / php security, but it isn't throwing that error any more with that set in php.ini.

No errors are showing up in Chrome when I run it now, but it just isn't displaying any of the HTML code that should be coming from the PHP echoed code (that should be displayed from the Python callback). There aren't any callback issues as it displays the JSONP when its set to display just a plain string through Python (non-PHP output). So, it's confirmed that it is working to display data across domains.

I don't know Python very well at all, so that could be the issue here. It's a perplexing issue for me and I put in few days trying to figure this all out before coming here to the experts!

Here is the **Plugin/HTML** code (included on a third party domain (cross domain), not example.com):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://example.com/widget/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="widget"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the **JavaScript** Code (widget.js):

```
(function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined) {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              scriptLoadHandler();
          }
      };
    } else {
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    main(); 
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        /******* Load CSS *******/
        var css_link = $("<link>", { 
            rel: "stylesheet", 
            type: "text/css", 
            href: "widget-styles.css" 
        });
       // css_link.appendTo('head');          



        //alert(element);

        /******* Load HTML *******/
        var jsonp_url = "https://example.com/cgi-bin/widget-python.py?callback=?";


         $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
          $('#widget').html("This data comes from another server: " + data.html);
        });
    });
}

})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

Here is the **Python** code included in /cgi-bin/ and called from widget.js (widget-python.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
import subprocess

params = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-Type: text/javascript\n"


proc = subprocess.Popen("php <pathtophpfile>.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = proc.stdout.read()
jsonp = "%s ( {'html': " + result + " } )"

#jsonp = "%s ( {'html': 'printastring' } )" THIS WORKS and prints into Chrome when its commented out, but its just a string, and what I need is the PHP output from the result variable above. 


#print result This prints the php code out perfectly into the command line when I run execute the python script from within /cgi-bin

print jsonp % params['callback'].value
```

AS FOR THE PHP CODE (pathtophpfile.php) that is supposed to be echoed out into Chrome, **its output is pure HTML div to div and it is displaying in the terminal when run, so Python is finding and running the PHP file.**. Thank you for your help, and I hope this is enough information, I'll be adding to it if it is not.